# How to create a http page on a https website?

Tags: http, https

I have a website hosted on Azure and SSL-enabled. I have a silly question:

Everything can still be accessed without https (e.g. "http://www.teacherspet.net.au"). How do I force everything except for the home page (which doesn't need login) to go https?

In other words, when people type in "http://www.teacherspet.net.au", it is redirected to "https://www.teacherspet.net.au".

Comment: Note:if you don't force https for all webpage, then you can't use HSTS, which is the *only* solution against MitM/sslstrip attacks.

Comment: Thanks but how to force https? And what is HSTS? I am not a cloud expert...